# What text processing does WikiCorpus perform in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I have trained a doc2vec model on the Wikipedia corpus using gensim and I wish to retrieve vectors from different documents.

I was wondering what text processing the WikiCorpus function did when I used it to train my model e.g. removed punctuation, made all the text lower case, removed stop words etc.

This is important as I wish to perform the same text processing on the documents I am inferring vectors from for greater consistency/accuracy with my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know precisely what's done, your best reference is the source code for `WikiCorpus` itself, which you can view in your local installation, or online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.py

Key functions in that file for dealing with the raw Wikipedia dump data include `process_article()`, `filter_wiki()` and `remove_markup()` – which ultimately also uses a local `tokenize()` function, that then relies on another `tokenize()` from the `gensim.utils` module.

And, `WikiCorpus` does in fact call that `utils.tokenize()` with a `lower=True` parameter to force lowercasing.

Further, that `utils.tokenize()` uses a `simple_tokenize()` function that, while it doesn't have a step that explicitly removes punctuation, looks for tokens via a [`PAT_ALPHABETIC` regex](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/b27d6ea11792bb658bfe4b605054a23bfb6c6c81/gensim/utils.py#L55) which selects tokens made of word-characters (`\w`) that don't start with digits (`\d`).